# Laplace method for a function that is no differentiable at one point

Tags: real-analysis, integration, laplace-method

The Laplace method states that:

> If $f(x)$ is twice differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f(x)$ has a unique
>   global maximum on $[a,b]$ at $x_0$ and $f''(x_0) <0$ \begin{align}
>  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \int_a^b e^{n f(x)} dx}{ \sqrt{\frac{2
>  \pi}{- n f''(x_0)}} e^{n f(x0)}}=1. \end{align}

**My question is does this method work if the function $f(x)$ is continuous but not differential at one only point  on $[a,b]$?**

For example, does Laplace method work
\begin{align}
f(x)=-|x|^3+x
\end{align}
for $[a,b]=[-1,1]$.

**Is there a method that does this without splitting the integral into two parts $[-1,0)$ and $(0,1]$?**

Comment: May I know whether you have a reference on the Laplace method result stated in the question? Most results I found assume that the derivative of $f$ is zero at the maximizer.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with [-1,0] and [0,1] separately . In each of these two subintervals you can apply Laplace method.

Comment: Yes, but is there a trick that does it with one integral.

Comment: Have you tried approximating f by differentiable functions which converge uniformly to f on [0,1] ? That may help but I am not sure.